# Question with general title and specific body attracted general answers, should it be dupe-target for questions which don't match body?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, title

For [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411544/3022952), while it has the title of "Delete column from pandas DataFrame", the body of the question is more specifically asking about why a particular syntax for deleting a column doesn't work. (It's definitely not a general "How do I delete a column?" question, as the OP provides a syntax that is already working for them.)

Possibly due to the general-sounding title, it has attracted a number of general "how to delete columns from pandas DataFrame" answers. This has apparently caused a gold-badge user to use that question as a dupe target for other "how to delete columns" questions. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29763620/3022952). (Which, I'll point out, isn't actually asking about how to delete a column from a DataFrame, but is instead asking about the related-but-distinct issue of creating a new DataFrame with a subset of the columns of another DataFrame.)

I attempted to clarify the issue by editing the title to be more specific (which was approved in review) and raising the issue with the gold-badge user, but the gold-badge user disagreed heavily (reverting the title edit), [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29763620/3022952):

> It's true that the intent of the OP was to question the syntax, but the post has grown to address the more broad question of how to delete a column. The answers in this [closed] post are carbon copies of the highest upvoted post there. The dupe stays.

*(Note that "carbon copies" is overstating things. While the functionality used is the same, the answers aren't literal copy/paste between the questions. Also, the most upvoted (& accepted) answer on the closed question provides a method not covered by the highest upvoted answer in the dupe target.)*

What's the appropriate course of action here? Is it really the case that someone making an overly-general answer to a question (one which the answer-author even admits in comments doesn't really even answer the question as-asked), can become a canonical "duplicate" target for other questions which aren't really related to the actual body of the question as-asked?

If editing the title of the question to be more specific isn't appropriate, should we instead edit the body of the question to be more general? After all, if this is being considered to be a canonical question about the broad topic of deleting a column, shouldn't the question itself reflect that fact? *(Though I don't know what the implications are regarding the currently accepted answer, which addresses the questions as-asked.)*

Comment: If the user still has an unanswered question, I would suggest asking a new one, with a better title and explanation of the situation, along with a link to the duplicate, explaining the difference between the two.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I don't think it's an issue of not getting the appropriate answers. Both questions here have accepted answers which address the as-asked questions and are sensitive to the differences between the two. -- It's actually the *non*-accepted answers which are causing the two questions to be considered as duplicates.

Comment: If a question's inaccurate title is causing confusion as to what the question is asking then *edit the title to better reflect the body of the question*.

Comment: @Servy As mentioned, I did that and that edit was promptly reverted by a gold-badge holder.

Comment: There are two issues: 1) your disagreement of the closure, and 2) your disagreement of the title. I'll address each one. As for 1), if you are familiar with pandas, you will understand that there is a heavy overlap between answers that address "Selecting all columns except one" and answers to "How to delete a column". You'll see the highest upvoted answers to these two posts are the same, that should validate my point. Accepts mean nothing except that the OP found the answer useful, which is not the prime focus of Stack Overflow (only a happy byproduct, as rightly mentioned many times here).

Comment: Regarding 2), I am all for editing titles for clarity -- I do it myself all the time. My point is that your edit did not improve the clarity at all, it only served to confuse and make the post less searchable. People looking to delete columns in pandas will find `drop` more useful than `del`. To put it bluntly, most people who land on that question do not care about the specifics of the `del` syntax. I reversed your edit for this reason. Hope that answers your questions or at least explains the motives behind my actions here. Cheers.

Comment: @cs95 can you propose a better title that reflect the content of the question?

Comment: @Braiam "Delete a column from a pandas DataFrame" (the title it already has). If you want to be pedantic, you could add "with del" but it is an unnecessary complication IMO.

Comment: @cs95 the user already knows how to delete a column from a panda dataframe. He's asking why the specific syntax he presumes is equivalent doesn't do the same thing.

Comment: I'm sure it is the case with many questions and those who answer them that we have to interpret what is most useful.  I'm often guessing at what an OP needs.  I'm interpreting if it is an XY problem.  I answer according to my instincts.  I have been correct in my guessing/interpretation more often than not.  I'd be willing to bet this is true for most successful answerers.  As it pertains to this question and as evidenced by the vote counts on the given answers people have searched for something that led them to the question in question and found an answer that was helpful.

Comment: @R.M. I think you are correct in your assessment of the situation.  But I would leave it alone considering how its evolved.  If you insisted on doing things "by the book" it would harm the usefulness to the community.

Comment: @Braiam I understand that, but this question is no longer about the OP. They have moved on. Over a million people have stumbled across this question via Google and I'll bet anything 99% of them did not care about the syntax the OP was asking about. Given the circumstances, changing the title can only do more harm than good. Think I've already said this before :)

Comment: @cs95 I think you're skipping over my main point that that question *shouldn't* be the question people most people land on. People interested in "How do I delete columns" should be pointed to some other question which actually asks about the topic (versus a question about syntax which attracted a useful-but-off-topic response due to a poor title). Editing the title to be more specific (and fixing up errant dupe links) means that future users won't click on the question unless they're interested in the specifics of `del` syntax -- they'll go to another, more relevant question instead.

Comment: @cs95 But if you're dead set against chainging the title, what would you say to changing the body of the question to match the title? If we don't care about the OP, why not just stomp on what they actually asked about, and make the question be about what you want it to be about?

Comment: @piRSquared I would argue that the usefulness to the community is harmed by having a canonical dupe-target be a question that isn't actually about the topic being "duped", and is only incidentally related due to a poorly worded title attracting an off-topic answer. People find this question on search (or through dupes), read the question as-written and then have a moment of "Wait -- this isn't what I'm interested in at all!". It would be so much better to have the question we point to be one which actually asks about the question at hand.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to fix here -- nothing is broken and the question is fine. I'd really prefer if people left it alone. As to your suggestion of changing the body, I would refrain from doing so because that would invalidate Wes' answer which is correct but as the accepted answer it would look horribly out of place without the context provided by the question. The title asks the more general question that others have answered.

Comment: I have looked through your profile and see that you do not have experience in the pandas tag. Do you have any particular reason to suggest that changing the title will improve things, and that the current title is causing issues?

Comment: @R.M. I respectfully disagree.  What resolution would satisfy you?  Are you content with being in a minority?  Or will you continue to solicit argument until things go your way?  If the community were to weigh in and disagree with me, I'd accept that.

Comment: As an anecdotal comment on this (now older) thread - I stumbled upon this question via Google when searching for "dataframe drop column", where it was the #1 SO result.  This question was most certainly _not_ about dropping columns in a dataframe, but rather about syntax oddities.  The accepted answer also addresses the syntax question, not the implementation question.  I don't believe SO operates on the premise of changing questions based on how people inappropriately choose to answer.  It is mis-titled in this actual user's opinion.

Comment: "I don't believe SO operates on the premise of changing questions based on how people inappropriately choose to answer" ehh I dunno, I think that's editorial discretion. There are questions that weren't asked with a specific intention but were found by people looking for a solution to a related (but not the same) problem. In that case I think it's important to consider usefulness for future readers before making edits.